# Order by timestamp desc but put 0 first

Tags: mysql

I have a table "test" with these columns:
id, name, timestamp

I made this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This puts the most recent records as the first result of the query. However, some timestamps are filled with "0" and I want to put those in front of the rest.

If I order by timestamp ASC then the whole result will be reversed. I just want timestamp=0 first, and the rest of the results descending.

How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this with an additional comparison in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM test 
ORDER BY (timestamp = 0) desc,
         timestamp DESC;
```

In MySQL, a boolean result, such as for `timestamp = 0`, is treated as `0` when false and `1` when true.  This makes it useful for many purposes, including such an `order by`.